# Advanced Code Formatting in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, optimization, formatting, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a way to get more possiblities of formatting code with C# in Visual Studio 2017, and after days of googling I felt like this seems to be the place where I can find my answer.

Features we're looking for is putting code assingments into a block, so that e.g.

```
public Foo(string name, string adress, int numberOfBooksOwned)
{
    Name = name;
    Adress = adress;
    NumberOfBooksOwned = numberOfBooksOwned;
}
```

becomes

```
public Foo(string name, string adress, int numberOfBooksOwned)
{
    Name               = name;
    Adress             = adress;
    NumberOfBooksOwned = numberOfBooksOwned;
}
```

It should also give the ability to override all of the formatting possibilities Visual Studio provides and save them into any kind of file, so that other members of my team can use those settings as well.

I'm aware that VS 2017 added a new kind of code formatting, but if I got that right, the added support for [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) does not do what I need.

I also tried *CodeMaid*, but this seems to require much performance, and I also think it does not match my needs.

Does anyone know about something that fits the above description, Preferably some kind of extensions that is compatible with Visual Studio 2017 or something built in since the latest version, to make it easy for anyone to use.

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: I don't think the 'formatted' one is more beautiful/readable/maintainable.

Comment: The kind of formatting in your example would drive me crazy - as names get longer the operator has to move further and further to the right. You end up with code looking like a table. I used to work with a contractor who insisting on doing this; fortunately as the technical lead I pulled rank on him and rejected his code during review. He did not stay long in the company.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste - and since my team agreed on this kind of formatting, it is quite annoying having to do this on your own every time, everytime when visual Studio thinks it's a good idea to remove all those spaces you added...

Comment: @Lithium in this case we handle it that with one or more lines between them they should be treated individually.

Comment: @M.Schmidt I wonder if your team understands the implications this formatting has to reading and understanding the code. The vertical spacing implies to the brain that the two concepts of the variable and its content are separate. Therefore reading, understanding and keeping the connection while thinking about the code becomes a lot more stressful. Just saying.

Comment: @M.Schmidt To my knowledge, nothing in VS2017 will accomplish what you want and I'm not aware of any code formatter that will. I'm pretty sure R# won't do this either. I think if this is the formatting you want, you're pretty much on your own here...

Comment: @MarkusDeibel MANY teams I've been a part of used this kind of formatting for SQL. While it certainly wasn't my favorite (and once I got into a position where I could influence the decision, I changed it), I can say I never felt "stressed" reading the code. Different things work for different teams. Definitely not the way you or I would do it, but if it works for them, that's fine with me.

Comment: @dman2306 this not normally not the kind of stress you feel directly. It is rather in the sense that the brain is normally trained to logically separate things that are visually separate. It requires just a little bit more brain power to keep the connection. If you have this a lot it can impair your overall performance. It's fine for two or three declarations five or more will make things harder.

Comment: This is called "table" formatting and was readily available in many IDE's.  Any formatting technique is _ALWAYS_ a personal preference and any coder worth their salt should be able to read and comprehend many versions of formatting(without alteration).  Wouldn't you expect a new hire to bend their personal preferences to yours?  As Polyfun is implying?  A team standard of formatting should be applied upon submission to source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I accidentally stumbled on an answer for you. Microsoft added this to the Productivity PowerTools for VS2017. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.AlignAssignments allows you to do exactly what your example shows by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+]`

Please make sure you take note of the one comment in the page:

> Note! This may conflict with your formatting settings. E.g. in C# you will need to disable: Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore spaces in declaration statements"

Considering this is an extension added by Microsoft I guess it's safe to say this feature is not built into VS2017.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be just what I've been looking for :)

Comment: The changes by the productivity tool though are not protected by the built in code formatting. Hopefully they add such a feature in a future release of Visual Studio. For those not using a US keyboard layout like me you also have to figure out the key combination to trigger the feature in your editor. German key code is Ctrl+Alt+´ (Apostrophe)